# How do I use a variable outside a function in react native?

Tags: react-native, variables

I need to use that variable "let result" outside of this function. I need to use that variable inside of another function. How can I get it?
My code looks like this:

```js
method: "GET",
headers: {
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.state.clientToken,
},
              })
              .then((response) => response.json())
              .then((responseJson) => {
                let result= JSON.parse((responseJson.lstsurveyoncode))
                let answer = JSON.parse(responseJson.lstsurveyoncode)[0].qoptions
                console.log("responsejson",result[1].QUESTIONCODE)
                console.log("answerrr",answer);
                console.log("data length",result.length);
                   this.setState({
                     isLoading:false,
                     dataresponse:result,
                    //  count:Object.keys(dataresponse).length
                    },function(){
                  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a global variable, and then update it inside your first function and in the second function you check if the variable is defined

```
let result;

function firstFunction(){
  result = 'Your Json Result'
}
function secondFunction(){
  if (!result) return;

  // Here you can use your variable result
}
```

Comment: It is very bad idea to use global variable for store async responses

Comment: So in the state?

Answer (score 0):

You should read about async-await and state managment in react-native.
For quick solution, you should mark your function with `async` modifier and `await` for result. Sample code below:

```js
async function yourRequest() {
  return new Promise((resolver, rejected) => {
    // your async request
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseJson => {
      const result = JSON.parse(responseJson.lstsurveyoncode)
      const answer = JSON.parse(responseJson.lstsurveyoncode)[0].qoptions
      // ...
      return {
        result: result,
        answer: answer,
      }
    })
}


async function handleResponse() {
  const response = await yourRequest()
  // and now, you can access to variables declared at `makeRequest` function  
  console.log(response.result)
  console.log(response.answer)
}
```

Comment: it shows as if the async can be used for only .ts files.